# Import value from iframe To the home page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom-events

Please help import value in iframe To the home page.

Example

1. htm

```html
<html dir="rtl">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>am</title>
</head>
<script>

function ok() {

    } 

</script>

<body>
<p align="center">
<iframe id="mm" src="2.htm" style="width:373px;height:84px;overflow:scroll" >


</iframe>
</p>
<p align="center">Import value from Page 2 here </p>
<p align="center"><input type="text" name="T1" size="20"></p>
<p align="center">
<input  type="submit" value="Import value from page 2" name="send1" onclick="ok(this)"   style="font-size: 14pt"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

2. htm

```html
<html dir="rtl">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>am</title>
</head>

<body>

<p align="center"><input type="text" name="T1" size="20" value="Hi"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please do not repeat yourself to bypass the request for more description, Please do not repeat yourself to bypass the request for more description Please do not repeat yourself to bypass the request for more description

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***>>>[Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+send+OR+pass+value+from+iframe+to+parent+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<***, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: And use type="button"